# Create an equilateral triangle mesh

Tags: precision, mesh, numeric

I am looking for a numerically stable way to create an equilateral triangle mesh.

My current approach is to generate the x coordinates of the vertices as `i * 1/stepsize` for even rows and `stepsize/2 + i * 1/stepsize` for odd rows. For the y coordinate I use `j * stepsize * sqrt(3.0/4.0)`, where `sqrt(3.0/4.0)` is the height of an equilaterial triangle with edge length 1.

Then I connect the grid vertices accordingly and the result looks nice:

[image: An equilateral triangle mesh]

But when I calculate the edge lengths and sort them, I see that two edges of almost the same length have a difference of about the double floating point epsilon and the error amplifies in the application where I would like to use the mesh.

Is there a way to create such a grid with exact edge lengths? Using the irrational square root probably introduces numeric instabilities, but I am not sure if it can be avoided.

Comment: Do you need the intersection points?  Would it be sufficient to draw 3 sets of parallel lines, rotated by 120º?

Comment: @DaveM. In the end I want to construct a hexagonal mesh and it is numerically important that all six vertices of a hexagon lie exactly on a circle.

Comment: Take a look at [meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo).

Comment: I believe having equilateral mesh where edge lengths diverge only in the last digit is more then enough. On practice when we mesh some objects of complex shape, the triangles are never equilateral, and the fight is to keep them not too much degenerate. Please clarify what software package is unstable with your meshes, probably the issue is not in meshes.

Comment: @fedor Own code with openmesh (with double precision mesh class) and Eigen.